# How to send a file when getting it with request?

Tags: node.js

I am making a request with a mandatory request and I need to send the response to the immediate user. I mean, I need to send the data just when I receive it.

I want request to make the request and as it obtains the data, it will send it to the user in real time.

I have the following code and all I can do in this way is save the file and then send it, which does not work at all well, because it takes even longer to send the file

```js
const def = (req,res)=> {
    const request = request.get("url")
    const getFile = fs.createWriteStream("path")
    
    request.on("error", ()=> {
        res.send("error")
    })
    request.pipe(getFile)

    getFile.on("finish", ()=>{

        const sendFile = fs.createReadStream("path")
        sendFile.on("data", (chunk)=>{
        
            res.send(chunk)
        })

        sendFile.on("finish", ()=> {

           res.end()
        })
    })

}
```

This works but has several problems.

1. I need to save the file
2. Until it is downloaded to the server, it cannot be sent
3. It is much slower than sending it in real time

I need something maybe like the following (I know that this does not exist in such a way but I try to give an idea)

```
request.on("data", (chunk)=>{
    res.send(chunk)
})

request.on("finish", ()=> res.end())

//or

getFile.on("data", (chunk)=>{

    res.send(chunk)
})

getFile.on("finish", () => res.end())
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the response directly to the client:

```
const def = (req, res) => {
  request
    .get("url")
    .on("error", () => {
      res.send("error")
    })
    .pipe(res)
}
```

[Official documentation.](https://github.com/request/request#streaming)

Comment: thanks!! so simple and it didn't occur to me.
You really saved me, I don't test positive because my reputation is less than 15, but when I raise my reputation, I do. It really worked!